# Celery task with multiple decorators not auto registering task name

Tags: python, celery, decorator, django-celery, python-decorators

I'm having a task that looks like this

```
from mybasetask_module import MyBaseTask

@task(base=MyBaseTask)
@my_custom_decorator 
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

and my base task looks like this

```
from celery import task, Task

class MyBaseTask(Task):
    abstract = True
    default_retry_delay = 10 
    max_retries = 3 
    acks_late = True
```

The problem I'm running into is that the celery worker is registering the task with the name

```
'mybasetask_module.__inner'
```

The task is registerd fine (which is the package+module+function) when I remove @my_custom_decorator from the task or if I provide an explicit name to the task like this

```
from mybasetask_module import MyBaseTask

@task(base=MyBaseTask, name='an_explicit_task_name')
@my_custom_decorator 
def my_task(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Is this behavior expected? Do I need to do something so that my tasks are registered with the default auto registered name in the first case when I have multiple decorators but no explicit task name?

Thanks,

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the [`functools.wraps()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to ensure that the wrapper returned by `my_custom_decorator` has the correct name:

```
from functools import wraps

def my_custom_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def __inner():
        return func()
    return __inner
```

The task name is taken from the function call that the `task` decorator wraps, but by inserting a decorator in between, you gave `task` your `__inner` wrapping function instead. The `functools.wraps()` decorator copies all the necessary metadata over from `func` to the wrapper so that `task()` can pick up the proper name.

Comment: That was spot on! Works now. Thanks for adding the explanation as well :). Makes sense to me now.